# How to remove a named route from Gorilla mux in go?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'd like to dynamically add/remove routes. 
According to the mux `Router` api it seems I can add routes, but not remove?

Comment: Why don't you swap the route to a function that always returns 404?

Comment: This should be part of a long-running process listening to docker labels for defining routes. It didn‘t seem elegant to have routes accumulating over time.

Comment: If they have a shared prefix, point it at a handler and do your own routing.